# Symfony 2: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object from Controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller, doctrine

Here's my Controller A:

```
<?php

namespace MonitoringBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

use MonitoringBundle\Entity\MarketplaceShop;

use MonitoringBundle\Controller\BController;

class AController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/A")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function AAction()
    {
        $B = new BController;

        $response = $B->BAction();

        return $this->render('MonitoringBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('BVar' => $response));
    }
}
?>
```

And thats Controller B:

```
<?php

namespace MonitoringBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

use MonitoringBundle\Entity\MarketplaceShop;

class BController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/B")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function BAction()
    {

        $id     = 'A2WPX7PK44TEBQ';
        $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $shop   = $em->getRepository('MonitoringBundle:MarketplaceShop')
                     ->findOneByUniqueShopId($id);
        if (!$shop) {
            // do something
            return new Response('Shop does not exist.');
        } else {
            // do something else
            return new Response('Shop exists!');
        }
    }

}
?>
```

When I call http://example.com/B, all is fine and I get a response:

> Shop does not exist.

But when I call http://example.com/A, I get an error:

> Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object
>   500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException

**Stack Trace:
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 291**

```
public function getDoctrine()
{
if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {
throw new \LogicException('The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application.');
}
```

Why does it work with /B/ but not with /A/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the @Christian Bujoreau answer, you can use forward method: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller

```
public function AAction()
{
    $response = $this->forward('MonitoringBundle:BController:BAction', array(
        // 'some_variable'  => $some_variable,
    ));

...

return $response;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to declare your B controller as service and call it in A controller through $this->container->get('controllerB');

In services.yml:

```
controllerB:
    class: MonitoringBundle\Controller\BController
    arguments:
        entity_manager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"


class AController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/A")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function AAction()
    {
        $B = $this->container->get('BController');

        $response = $B->BAction();

        return $this->render('MonitoringBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('BVar' => $response));
    }
}


class BController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/B")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function BAction()
    {

        $id     = 'A2WPX7PK44TEBQ';
        $shop   = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MonitoringBundle:MarketplaceShop')
                     ->findOneByUniqueShopId($id);
        if (!$shop) {
            // do something
            return new Response('Shop does not exist.');
        } else {
            // do something else
            return new Response('Shop exists!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to try this.

Just for understandig: Why does it not work the way i did it?

@CristianBujoreanu

Comment: Check this for more details about this topic: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/controller/service.html